# VS Code shows error when there is none | TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual Studio Code and tried to learn some TypeScript 
Now I entered following code:

```
function greeting(person: string) {
    return "Hallo: " + person +"!";
}
var user = "clemens";
console.log(greeting(user));
```

VS Code now underlines **greeting** in `function greeting` 
Am I doing something wrong or is this a VS Code problem

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: And what is the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you hover the mouse over greeting, you’ll get the error message. I think TS expects you to declare a return type

`function greeter(n:string):string {}`

Comment: Got the same problem with vscode, even tried to reinstall it but it doesn't help, anyone found a solution?

Comment: Open the `problems` tab in VS Code to see what the problem is. Most likely, it's that your function returns `void` so you can't return a string.